# XML delete node according to timestamp C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, timestamp

I need help on how to "automatically" delete a node based on timestamp. A particular date is defined by the user inside a xml document e.g. 17/9/2006 
Can someone provide me an example? 
Thanks in advance!

```
   <root>
    <element>
    </element>
    <timestamp time="2016-09-16T13:45:30">
    </timestamp>
    <--how do I delete element based on the given timestamp?-->
    </root>

  //UNTESTED CODE

     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("time.xml");
     var name = doc.Descendants("root")
        .Where(n => n.Attribute("time").Value == "2016-09-16T13:45:30")
        .Select(n => (string)n) 
        .First(); 
      <--how can I delete it based on timestamp-->
         name.Element("element").Remove();
```

Comment: This is no valid xml. the timestamp node should have an attribute whose value is your actual timestamp.

Comment: You mean the standard datetime format, correct, but the above is just a demo xml.

Comment: Since your xml is now valid, what is your exact problem ? Parsing the xml and identifying the node, or parsing the ISO date format ?

Comment: I don't know how to use timestamp function. I'm familiar enough with LINQ, identifying the node isn't an issue. thanks.

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: @RichaGarg code has been updated

Comment: So Given a DateTime , you want to delete the xml element on the basis of  `timestamp` attribute? Do you want to delete the only the timestamp tag or anything else?

Comment: Generally i want to know the way on how to delete an xml element based on timestamp attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets suppose you want to compare with a DateTime variable `inputDate`.

```
// I have formatted yor XML and structured it. "root" is the the parent node. Elements are the child elements of root consisting of timestamp tag.

 string xmlInput =  @"
 <root>
 <element>
 <timestamp time='2016-09-16T13:45:30'>
 </timestamp>
 </element>
 <element>
 <timestamp time='2016-10-16T13:45:30'>
 </timestamp>
 </element>
 </root>";

    XDocument  xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);
    xdoc.Descendants("root").Elements("element").
                             Where(x => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(x.Element("timestamp").Attribute("time").Value,null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind).Date, inputDate.Date) ==0).
                             ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
```

I have compared the xml date `timestamp` for each element with `inputdate` for equality of only Date not the time. You can have any condition you want.

Note: You need to refer using System.Globalization;

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Τhanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Parsing ISO 8601 date/time format:

```
string input = "2016-09-16T13:45:30";
DateTime converted = DateTime.Parse(input, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Once the date converted to a DateTime type, you can use it identify the node you wish to remove (and using LinQ for that is highly recommended).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my code.  So I will compare "converted" with time attribute?

Comment: When you parse your XML, you will convert the time attribute, which is of type string, to a DateTime with the code snippet I provided, and compare this DateTime to the one you use to decide whether the node should be deleted or not.