# What does DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind enumeration mean?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I was reading this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508178/xml-delete-node-according-to-timestamp-c-sharp) where I came across this enumeration value `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`. I'm trying to understand it now. I looked into MSDN docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which says:

> The DateTimeKind field of a date is preserved when a DateTime object
> is converted to a string using the "o" or "r" standard format
> specifier, and the string is then converted back to a DateTime object.

The timestamp pointed by `input` variable in the post I referred in the previous paragraph is as below:

```
<timestamp time='2016-09-16T13:45:30'>
```

I ran her code and it works. Now it has become bit messy to correlate all the information I have:

1. The above time stamp contains some identifier `T`
2. The MSDN documentation talks about `o` and `r` format specifiers which it doesn't tell what it is?
3. If you go into dig more details on `DateTimeKind` enumeration on the MSDN link I've quoted above it says nothing about `o` and `r` format specifiers. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) is the link which says:

   ```
   Member Name   |  Description
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Local         |  The time represented is local time.
   ```

   ---

   ```
   Unspecified   |  The time represented is not specified as either local time or Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
   ```

   ---

   ```
   Utc           |      The time represented is UTC.
   ```

So can someone help me understand `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` enumeration and how it works?

Comment: For details on o and r, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `T` is just part of the ISO-8601 format

Comment: The `T` is not a format specifier in example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So I was finally able to understand this and sharing the same information here if it can be helpful for others too:

First part is conversion of C# **DateTime** object into string. There are many format specifiers to do that but for us **r** and **o** format specifiers are of concern to us with regards to **DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind**. You can see all date time format specifiers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). See what happens when we do the conversion in code using these format specifiers:

```
//r corresponds to RFC 1123 format (GMT date time format)
var gmtDateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("r"); //gives Fri, 23 Sep 2016 15:39:21 GMT 

//o corresponds to ISO 8601 (Local date time format)
var localDateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("o"); //gives 2016-09-23T15:39:21.8899216+05:30
```

You can clearly see that string date time being output has the information embedded inside it which suggests:

- **Fri, 23 Sep 2016 15:39:21 GMT** is of **DateTimeKind.Utc** (**GMT** text is present)
- **2016-09-23T15:39:21.8899216+05:30** represents a date time of **DateTimeKind.Local** (**T** character is present as per **ISO 8601** standard)

Now comes the second part. If I've to convert the date time strings stored in `gmtDateTimeString` and `localDateTimeString` back to a date time object then we need to parse them. So with the help of **DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind** enumeration value passed to **DateTime.Parse** API you actually signify that time zone information is already baked in the string and API parses the date time appropriately using that information.

Normally, when date time data is transferred over the wire in XML format then **ISO 8601** format is used which I saw in the post which I referred before posting the question in this thread. So while parsing such a date time string obtained from an XML document it was appropriate to use the **DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind** to get the right date time value as per the time-zone information present in the string.

Answer (score 16):

I had a hard time understanding the other answers so I decided to do some resarch myself. Luckily, the source code for the .NET library is available online.

[`DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` has a comment in the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimestyles.cs,49):

```
// Attempt to preserve whether the input is unspecified, local or UTC
```

It is more or less just as vague as the MSDN documentation on [`DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The DateTimeKind field of a date is preserved when a DateTime object is converted to a string using the "o" or "r" standard format specifier, and the string is then converted back to a DateTime object.

By navigating the Reference Source website it can be seen that `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` is used very little. Essentially, if the flag is set then [it **may** modify the kind of the `DateTime` to `DateTimeKind.Utc`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2615). So this is the effect of setting this flag: Sometimes the `Kind` property of the parsed `DateTime` value is set to `Utc`.

Exactly when this happens is controlled by the internal flag [`ParseFlags.TimeZoneUtc`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,da17d11780eb1faf). It is more complicated to determine when this flag gets set but as far as I can tell the parser will set this flag if the timezone is specified using either `Z` or `GMT`. There is [a comment about this in the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,1052):

```
// NOTENOTE : for now, we only support "GMT" and "Z" (for Zulu time).
```

My conclusion is that if a timestamp is formatted using either `o` or `r` and `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` is used while parsing the timestamp then the `Kind` of the resulting `DateTime` value is set to `Utc` if the timezone in the string is the UTC timezone.

However, what happens when the flag is not set? The best way to determine this is to do some actual testing of the two format specifiers.

## The Round-trip ("O", "o") format specifier

When using the `o` format specifier the timezone of the timestamp will either be `Z` for UTC or `+/-` the offset from UTC (e.g. `2017-02-26T22:55:15.4923368+01:00`). Here is a table that shows the value of the `Kind` property of a `DateTime` value parsed from a round-trip timestamp:

```
Timezone | RoundTripKind | Kind
---------+---------------+------
"Z"      | Not specified | Local
"Z"      | Specified     | Utc
Not "Z"  | Not specified | Local
Not "Z"  | Specified     | Local
```

*If you want to parse a timestamp in round-trip format and you expect the timezone of the timestamp to be UTC then you should specify `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` to ensure that the parsed `DateTime` value has kind `Utc`.*

## The RFC1123 ("R", "r") format specifier

When using the `r` format specifier the timestamp will always contain `GMT` (even if the kind of the original `DateTime` is not `Utc`) thus a table for the `r` format has no need for a `Timezone` column. However, I have discovered that `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact` behave differently when a RFC1123 timestamp is parsed:

```
Method     | RoundTripKind | Kind
-----------+---------------+------------
Parse      | Not specified | Local
Parse      | Specified     | Utc
ParseExact | Not specified | Unspecified
ParseExact | Specified     | Unspecified
```

When using the `Parse` method a timestamp in the RFC1123 format behaves the same as a UTC timestamp in the round-trip format. However, for some reason the `ParseExact` method ignores the `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` flag. This is not the case when a round-trip formatted timestamp is parsed.

*If you want to parse a timestamp in RFC1123 format you should either use the `Parse` method and specify `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` or if you prefer the `ParseExact` method you will have to modify the kind of the parsed timestamp to `Utc`. You do that by creating a new timestamp using the [`DateTime.SpecifyKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.specifykind) method.*

## Conclusion

When parsing round-trip and RFC1123 timestamps specify `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` to ensure that the `Kind` property of the parsed `DateTime` value is `Utc`.

If a round-trip timestamp has a non-zero offset then you will have to parse the timestamp into a `DateTimeOffset` value to preserve the offset (`Local` does not tell you what the offset is - just that it probably is different from 0).

Do not use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse RFC1123 timestamps (or change the kind to `Utc` after the timestamp has been parsed).

Answer (score 4):

The roundtrip format is meant for "machine consumption" - it can easily be parsed back into the same DateTime value.
Most of the other formats are for "human consumption", to show the date (possibly including time) to a person.